# After pressing back button, exoplayer in recyclerview continues in background

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

My adapter code is:-

```
class VideoAdapter(
    private var mContext: Context,
    private var mvideos: List<VID>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.videos_adapter, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val videoid = mvideos[position]

        holder.vidId.text = videoid.getilp()

        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
        val videoLink = Uri.parse(videoid.getVideoUrl())
        val mediaSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(videoLink))

        holder.mPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build()
        holder.playerView.player = holder.mPlayer
        holder.mPlayer!!.playWhenReady = true
        holder.mPlayer!!.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        holder.mPlayer!!.stop()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mvideos.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var mPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer? = null
        var playerView: PlayerView = itemView.videos_ret
        var vidId: TextView = itemView.videos_id_ret
    }
}
```

The activity code is :-

```
class videos : AppCompatActivity() {

    var valueListener: ValueEventListener? = null

    val wimagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("videos")

    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var videoAdapter: VideoAdapter? = null
    private var vid1: MutableList<VID>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videos)

        recyclerView = videos
        recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 1)

        vid1 = ArrayList()
        videoAdapter = baseContext?.let { VideoAdapter(it, vid1 as ArrayList<VID>) }
        recyclerView?.adapter = videoAdapter

        wimagesRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    videoAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    val video = snapshot.getValue(VID::class.java)
                    if (video != null) {
                        videos.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        (vid1 as ArrayList<VID>).add(video)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        wimagesRef.removeEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    videoAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    val videos = snapshot.getValue(VID::class.java)
                    if (videos != null)
                        (vid1 as ArrayList<VID>).clear()

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Everthing is working fine but when I press back button, I came to my last activity but still the video continues to play in the background. The audio of the video still continues to play while I am in the other activity. I want to destroy that activity on backpress. Someone please help me.

Comment: If you understand Java, I think that this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/TheMovieDbApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM) might help.

Comment: I don't understand. I tried but I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your onDestroy() function

```
StyledPlayerView.player.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

in **videoAdapter**

create a global variable for **SimpleExoPlayer** and use a secondary constructor to initialise SimpleExoPlayer

private  lateinit var exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer

```
//then create a public method

  fun clearVideo(){
     if(exoPlayer != null){
      exoPlayer. stop() or  clear() whatever function is provided 
      notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
  }
```

change

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val videoid = mvideos[position]

    holder.vidId.text = videoid.getilp()

    val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
    val videoLink = Uri.parse(videoid.getVideoUrl())
    val mediaSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(videoLink))
    exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build()
    holder.mPlayer = exoPlayer
    holder.playerView.player = holder.mPlayer
    holder.mPlayer.playWhenReady = true
    holder.mPlayer.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
   
}
```

Now from

> class videos : AppCompatActivity() {

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    clearAll()
}

fun clearAll(){
   //Call the function in adapter
     videoAdapter.clearVideo()
    finish()
    //this will call the destroy() to clear the lister
}
```

Try this

Comment: No, Its not working. array is of type list. so, I convert emptyArray<VID>() to emptyArray<VID>().toList()

Comment: I also tried 
    fun clearAll() {
        videoAdapter = VideoAdapter(this, emptyList())
        finish()
    }

Comment: We cannot send emptylist in recyclerview adapter

Comment: Try the new changes above

Comment: You can also convert private constructor in adapter to secondary

Comment: Now the videos are not playing in the background but while playing the videos all videos play and pause simultaneously.

Comment: Is there any other way to show thumbnail of the video in one activity and play videos in another activity.

Comment: ok you can add

`holder.mPlayer.stop()`
in your adapter
I removed it before

Comment: I have already done that. But when I press any key in one video then it is applied on all the videos in the operator.

Comment: try the new update

Comment: I removed the init{} constructor I created and also check if exoplayer is now null before calling stop()

Comment: It also didn't worked out. Now same problem is still their. First I thought it worked out but it didn't.

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455134/exoplayer-with-recyclerview